# Zend Studio 7.2 showing error on namespaces?

Tags: doctrine, zend-studio

I have these namespaces defined in my bootstrap file:

```
use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader,
    Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager,
    Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mongo,
    Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
```

But there is an error on the first line above:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'Doctrine', expecting '('
```

7.X is supposed to have namespace support, but it's showing errors ALL throughout my project. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a thought, but do you definitely have your project configured for PHP 5.3 support? Our installation here defaults to PHP 5.2 for new projects.

Comment: Ahhh. It is set to "use default". Which may not be 5.3. That's probably it. Duh!